# how to download zip file used by AJAX java

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, zip

After passing the data to the controller through ajax,
I finished creating a zip file in the C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp folder.
It does open well in above folder I mentioned it.
But when I click the jsp button and download it, the zip file does not open. It even takes up space.
I searched that the download function cannot be implemented using only ajax,
so I added xhr, but I am having difficulty because I do not know much about xhr.
Can you tell me where is wrong?

- JSP - AJAX

```
    $("#btnFileDown").click(function() {
            var obj = $("#grid")
            var ids = obj.getGridParam("selarrrow");
            var id = obj.jqGrid("getDataIDs");
            var params = new Array();
            
            for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                var data = obj.getRowData(ids[i]);
                params.push(data);
            }
            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url : baseUrl + "fileDownload.et",
                data : {data:JSON.stringify(params)},
                success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                            alert("Success");
                            let disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition'); 
                            let filename; 
                            if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) { 
                                let filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/; 
                                let matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition); 
                                if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, ''); 
                            } 
                            let blob = new Blob([data]); 
                            let link = document.createElement('a'); 
                            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
                            link.download = filename; 
                            link.click();
                        },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("Failed => " + errorThrown);
                        }
            });
        });
```

- server

```
    @RequestMapping("fileDownload.et")
    @Transactional
    public void fileDownload(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> param, ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletResponse response) throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {

// After creating ZipFile Code.
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +URLEncoder.encode(zipFile.getName(), "UTF-8"));
            response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
            
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
            ServletOutputStream fout = response.getOutputStream();
            
            byte b[] = new byte[(int) zipFile.length()];
            int leng = 0;
            
            while ((leng = fin.read(b)) > 0) {
                fout.write(b, 0, leng);
            }
}
```

search all website and ask my question in stackoverflow
but it doesnt reponse me anybody.

Comment: Try closing out your streams after the while loop? fin.close(); fout.close();

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I Solved this problem.
To use blob, I had to upgrade the jquery version.
And added code xhrFields in Ajax.

Comment: Don’t reinvent the wheel. Use [`Files.copy(zipFile.toPath(), fout);`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,java.io.OutputStream)). And get a habit of using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), then you don’t need to remember to close.